# Mojolicious::Lite - inserting picture question

Tags: perl, image, mojolicious

When I run this script and open `http://my_server/picture` I get instead the picture the `logo`-string.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/picture' => sub {
    shift->render();
};

app->start;

__DATA__
@@ picture.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
<img src="/absolute/path/TEST.jpg" alt="logo" />
<p>World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open this HTML-piece as normal HTML-file I get the picture.

What is the right way, to insert a picture with Mojolicious::Lite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `public` directory is intended for static data. Just create it next to your script and put the image in. When development server with default settings is running, you can access it on url:

```
http://localhost:3000/TEST.jpg
```

So your template can contain:

```
<img src="/TEST.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use: [Base64 encoded DATA files](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mojolicious/lib/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering.pod#Base64-encoded-DATA-files):

```
...
__DATA__
@@ picture.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
<img src="/absolute/path/TEST.jpg" alt="logo" />
<p>World</p>
</body>
</html>

@@ TEST.jpg (base64)
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAZABkAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAD6APoDASIA
...
```